# Firestore rules Path not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying make a function i Firestore Rules that checks if the authorized user is the owner of the document. I have used the simulator for testing the outcomes of the functions and this is some of those things i tried:

```
return request.auth.uid == 'fePQ2zznGnh7LkDZXonz' && database == '(default)'
```

returns **true**

```
resource.data.user is path
```

returns **true**

```
return resource.data.user == path('/databases/(default)/documents/users/fePQ2zznGnh7LkDZXonz')
```

returns **true**

```
return resource.data.user == path(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
```

returns **false**

```
return resource.data.user == path(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).bind({"database": database, "userId": request.auth.uid});
```

returns **false**

I've read their docs about path, and I can't seem to find what I missed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path

In the simulator i have put in the following

```
Simulation type: get
location: /servers/6CKqA8ifVsRW3NNww3WF
authentication: true
provider: custom
payload: {
  "uid": "fePQ2zznGnh7LkDZXonz",
  "token": {
    "sub": "",
    "aud": "h4hosting-6f5c8",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "custom"
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to retrieve is to check if `resource.data.user`'s uid is the same as `request.auth.uid`. `resource.data.user`'s data type in the firestore database is a document reference with the value `users/fePQ2zznGnh7LkDZXonz`

Anyone that can point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the following rule?

```
return resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)
```

This should work if the document is already stored in Firestore.
If you want to verify that authenticated user only writes documents belonging to him, you have to check it in the "request":

```
request.resource.data.user
```